# JSMin usage problem

Tags: javascript, minify

I want to use JSMin to minify js files, but I'm confused how to install it in my windows machine and how to use it... I tried to find any resource by no luck. can anyone please help me with this?

Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, here is a full tutorial about JSMin:
[JSMIN, The JavaScript Minifier](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html)

You can find out how to use it in the "**Command Line Options**" part.

but i really recommend ( my favorite ):
[**Dean Edwards JS Packer V3.0**](http://dean.edwards.name/packer/)

Comment: but when I try to execute the command gives this error :( "The system cannot execute the specified program"

Comment: if you allready downloaded the program,
then you might be missing the .NET package needed to run it.

Comment: i think it will be a lot easier if you use the packer i recommended ( it is also better then the one you are trying to use ), and it dosent require any installation.
you can download the latest .Net pack here: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17851

Comment: Finally I got to know the exe link provides doesn't work properly, I got it from a friend and then it worked... Thanks a lot for the help...

Comment: This suggests something else than providing answer to the question.

Comment: @CharlieH - How come? the guy wanted to install it on he's machine. i provided a link to the full tutorial on how to do so. (btw, you do realize this is a question from 2011?)

Comment: @Dementic - This is the reason why SO don't recommend posting only links. They eventually become irrelevant and render your question useless.

Comment: @CharlieH - The link works and describes the installation and command line, Where is the problem exactly? From "This suggests something else" you are now about "SO don't recommend posting links only". Which one is it?

Comment: Your link doesn't show exactly how it should be operated. "Command line options" talks about an optional parameter - not the exact usage of it with example. 

You recommend something without answering the question properly. 

So you have both these problems in your answer.

Comment: @CharlieH - as you see by the OP, at the time this was asked there was NO information available. I gave the user some information to help him advance with he's problem. What have you done beside complaining?

Comment: Posting only links in SO questions is not helpful and is not advised. I have the right to point that out in my comments. You can't brand me as complaining when I'm doing that.

Comment: @CharlieH - Please look at the rules back at 2011, when this was posted. You seem to have a lot of spare time on your hand, maybe you can use that time to help people.

Comment: I am spending my spare time to help people in a greater context by trying to get some people to post only useful answers.

There is no question about rules. The question is about one's own judgement about the true usefulness of the answers throughout their existence.

Comment: Have fun then. I'm out of this useless conversation.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html

At the bottom:

> You can get a [zip file containing an MS-DOS.exe file](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.zip), or you can get the C source code and build it yourself.

Comment: Command line usage (from that site) is  jsmin.exe <input.js >output.js

Comment: This doesn't answer the question well. Anyone goes there can see that the documentation is just empty.

Comment: @CharlieH: are you saying you get a blank page? The link works fine for me.

Comment: This page doesn't provide a clear documentation for exact usage. You shouldn't include links in your answer without explanation.

Comment: @CharlieH: No worries, I'm not (anymore). Feel free to edit this answer to provide more information (it's community wiki after all).